# Hosting Socket.io Server over LAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm building Socket.IO's example chat project (with some modifications) and I've been trying to get people to connect with both `localhost:3000` and `127.0.0.1:3000`, but neither are working. Am I missing something? (If there's a blatantly obvious problem, sorry. I suck with networking.)

index.js:

```
var app=require('express')();
var http=require('http').Server(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(http);
var chalk=require('chalk');

var online=0;
var prt=process.argv[2]===undefined?3000:process.argv[2];

process.stdin.on('data',function(){
    var str=String(process.stdin.read());
    if(str.search("!quit")){
        io.emit('chat message','Console: stopping server.');
        process.exit();
    }
});

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    online++;
    console.log(chalk.green('joined  |',chalk.cyan(online),'online'));

    socket.on('chat message',function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message',msg);
        console.log(chalk.magenta('message |',msg));
    });

    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        online--;
        console.log(chalk.red('left    |',chalk.cyan(online),'online'));
    });
});

http.listen(prt,function(){
    console.log(chalk.yellow('SIOChat listening on',chalk.cyan(prt)));
});
```

---

index.html (omitted css for readability):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SIOChat</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id='messages'></ul>
        <form action=''>
            <input id='m' autocomplete='off'/><button>Send</button>
        </form>
        <script src='https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js'></script>
        <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js'></script>
        <script>
            var socket=io();

            var name=prompt('Enter a nickname','Guest');

            $('form').submit(function(){
                socket.emit('chat message',name+': '+$('#m').val());
                $('#m').val('');
                return false;
            });

            socket.on('chat message',function(msg){
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can the same be achieved on android?through java-library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`localhost` is the name for *your own machine*. If another machine on the network attempts to connect to `localhost`, they will be connecting to *their own machine*. Similarly, `127.0.0.1` is what's called the *loopback* address, and tells the socket to connect directly to the your own machine (`localhost` is a host name that actually resolves to the `127.0.0.1` ip address in most cases).

Other machines on the network will need to connect to your machine by IP address.

You can find out what your ip address is by typing `ipconfig` at the command prompt (on Windows), or `ifconfig` on Linux/OSX.

For example, if your ip address is `192.168.1.100`, then other machines will need to connect to your computer using an address like `192.168.1.100:3000`

Comment: Age of Empires and Minecraft LAN parties teach you this principle very quickly. :)